# jqPlot: Pie Chart not displaying label on slices even after setting showDataLabels:true

Tags: jqplot, pie-chart

I am trying to render a pie chart using following piece of code:

```
plot1 =jQuery.jqplot('chart2',
    [[['data1', 80],['data2',20]]],
    {
      title: ' ',
      seriesDefaults: {
        shadow: false,
        renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,

        rendererOptions: {
//        fill: false,
          sliceMargin: 4,

          showDataLabels: true
        }
      },
      grid: {
                                    //drawGridLines: true,
                                    background: 'transparent'
                                },
      legend: { show:true, location: 'n' }
    }
  )
      });
```

When i set fill to false the data lables are visible on the slices but if i set it to true, it is not getting displayed on the slices. It s actually getting printed behind the pie.Could not find any css to change z axis value too.Is there anything i am doing wrong in the code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well your code seems to work well : [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/Y6gRY/1/) Your problem seems to code from an other part of your code not Jqplot. However you can try to specify **div.jqplot-data-label{z-index: 1000;}** to force your data labels to be displayed on the foreground

Comment: @AnthonyLeGovic  Thanks a lot.Setting the Z-index solved my issue.

Comment: I have put it as answer as you can accept it for further visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your code seems to work well : [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/Y6gRY/1/) Your problem seems to came from an other part of your code not Jqplot. However you can try to specify

```
div.jqplot-data-label{z-index: 1000;}
```

to force your data labels to be displayed on the foreground